# Cannot connect remotely to my email server using PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, pop3, dovecot

I'm writing a PHP script using PHPMailer to send automaticaly emails.
For test purposes , I've used a Gmail account with an application passsword and everything works fine.
When I replace the Gmail account  config with my professional email , the PHP connection script keeps loading a while and ends up with this message.
the SMTPDebug is set to 3.

> 2015-11-16 22:43:30 SERVER -> CLIENT: +OK Dovecot ready. 2015-11-16 22:43:30 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost

What does this mean ?

Here is the PHP function that Im using to test the connection to the email server

```
<?php

require('../PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); 

function smtpMailer() {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // active SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  
    $mail->Host = 'mail.mycompany.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    //$mail->Username = "myaccount@mycompany.com";
    //$mail->Password = "mypassword";
    $mail->SetFrom = "myaccount@mycompany.com";
    $mail->FromName = 'foxy';
    $mail->addAddress('sendTo@gmail.com', 'John Doe');  
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                

     $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
     $mail->Body = 'This is the body in plain text ';


if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}


}

smtpMailer();

?>
```

Error

```
2015-11-17 01:44:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mycompany.com ESMTP Ready 2015-11-17 01:44:14 
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2015-11-17 01:44:14    
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mycompany.com Hello localhost 250 HELP 2015-11-17 01:44:14 
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 2015-11-17 01:44:15    
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 root@localhost... Sender ok 2015-11-17 01:44:15   
CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 2015-11-17 01:44:16  
SERVER -> CLIENT: 503 non-authenticated user. Please check mail before sending. 2015-11-17 01:44:16 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 503 non-authenticated user. Please check mail before sending. 2015-11-17 01:44:16   
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-11-17 01:44:16  
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 goodbye. 2015-11-17 01:44:16  SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: sendTo@gmail.com: non-authenticated user. Please check mail before sending. 
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: sendTo@gmail.com: non-authenticated user. Please check mail before sending.
```

Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code that working for I am using

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Username = "no-reply@mycompany.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->FromName = "Any Text";
$mail->Subject = $sub;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $code;
$mail->Host = "192.168.20.47"; // Is IP example that I show here 
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->From = $mail->Username;
if ($mail->Send()) {
    echo "Message send!";
}
else {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

hope it can help.

Comment: Yes It worked , but after removing
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
Thank you